# Could not load file or assembly 'Ninject'

Tags: c#, asp.net, ninject, package-managers

I installed Ninject packages via package manager console:

```
install-package Ninject.Mvc5
install-package Ninject.Web.WebApi
```

Because I didn't specify version It installed I suppose the latest available version (**3.3.0**) of the packages and their dependencies.
Among other dependencies It installed **Ninject 3.3.3**.

Then I realized I needed version **3.2.1.0** so I uninstalled Ninject.Mvc5 and Ninject.Web.WebApi version 3.3.0 with all their dependencies (GitHub showed 0 changes after uninstalling process) and installed version 3.2.1.0.
**Ninject** which goes with this is version **3.2.0**.

So, when I run the app I got following error:

> "**Could not load file or assembly** '**Ninject**, **Version=3.3.3.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

I checked assembly's manifest definition via **ildasm** and there are no any reference to Ninject 3.3.3. All references are to Ninject 3.2.0.
Also in **.csproj**, **packages.config** and **bin** folder Ninject version is 3.2.0.

I am able to resolve this problem with Web.config:

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Ninject" publicKeyToken="c7192dc5380945e7" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.3.3.0" newVersion="3.2.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

but obviously, there is a place where still exist reference to this **Ninject 3.3.3** version which has deleted. Where is that place, can someone figure out?

Comment: Assembly version details would be there in Manifest Metadata, could you try clean up , rebuild all options, post deleting all the project binaries physically, basically the manifest is important part of assembly probing and there its finding the old reference which it is trying to load. You can check that using ILDASM or Assembly log viewer, which suggests assembly binding details

Comment: I am now certain this is the case of binary corruption, you could just delete the bin folder and recreate the new binaries, also by the point that Github doesn't shows any change I assume you are referring to Packages.config for Nuget and you are not committing the actual binary to Git, which is never a good idea